# Receiving SOAP messages in APEX

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, webservices, visual-workflow, httpresponse

I have been trying to figure this for a long time now, my issue is :

**There is an outbound message that is being sent from a workflow rule (on create) with the Record Id, I want to capture this message in salesforce by exposing a Public (salesforce sites) service (SOAP), get the ID perform some business logic and return an OK response.**

Not being able to get any lead in this direction; I came across this post [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23288/matching-a-webservice-class-to-an-inbound-request-whose-format-i-cannot-change)

**which explains on using REST to retrieve the message and headers, I have manged to implement that part but now the catch is that I am not able to build/send an appropriate response to notify the server that the message is received (in short an OK response ) which causes the same message to be sent again and again.**

I would appreciate any lead on either of the approaches, 
**Thanks a Ton!**

Comment: I suggest you look at the Web Services and SOAP section of the Apex Developer's Guide https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_chapter.htm, the REST API Developer's Guide https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm and the SOAP API Developer's Guide https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/misc_apex.htm. I think you'll find these helpful. Lots of examples and sample code.

Comment: Can I please know if u got the approach to send appropriate response to notify the server that the message is received ?

Comment: Hey @VenkateshBabu, unfortuntely I couldn't figure out a way to send the right response back to notify salesforce that the message was received correctly (200).

Comment: @user18363 here is your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured this out almost after two years, posting the solution so that anyone else stuck on this issue can find a way of doing this.

The goal here was to send the correct anticipated ack back to SFDC as a conformation that the Out-bound message has been received. The way to do that is to set your response body in the following way **(the soap envelop is the important part)**:

```
res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(
    '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">' +
        '<soapenv:Body>' +
            '<notificationsResponse xmlns=\"http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound\">' +
                '<Ack>true</Ack>' +
            '</notificationsResponse>' +
        '</soapenv:Body>' +
    '</soapenv:Envelope>'
);
```

This does the job.