# Matching a WebService class to an inbound request

Tags: apex, webservices, soap, wsdl

I went through the answer given at [matching a WebService class to an inbound request whose format I cannot change](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23288/matching-a-webservice-class-to-an-inbound-request-whose-format-i-cannot-change) but i am not clear how rest class POST method will get called from outbound message

I have set the endpoint url for outbound message as the restresource urlmapping of custom rest api developed in apex

I am sending session Id for authentication but sessoin id for outbound meassage comes in request body and not in header

If anybody can provide similar example it would be really helpful for me

Comment: client of your webservice is using SFDC SOAP API or REST API?

Comment: my client is same salesforce org. I am sending out the outbound message and trying to capture the same in the custom rest api developed in the same org @crop1645

Comment: outbound message as in Workflow Outbound message? I think these require a SOAP endpoint, not REST endpoint

Comment: Generally speaking you can't direct an outbound message directly to a Salesforce Org as the outbound SOAP request will not have the required Session ID to authenticate the request. Yes you can embed the SessionID in the SOAP message, but the request will still be rejected. Unless you are going to host the endpoint in Sites or something similar?